# How to create a local blast db using ftp

Tags: ftp, bioinformatics, blast

I want to run blast searches which compare a gene to a genome of one specific orgnaism. Something like below where I can put this in a loop and keep changing the value of $OrganismName

```
blastn -query $Gene -db /Volumes/genomes/$OrganismName -out Acan_blast.txt -evalue 0.00001 -outfmt 6
```

From what I have seen elsewhere on the web it looks like I need to create a local database using an ftp server. I've been trying to do this with no success doing things like

```
makeblastdb -in ./index.html -out genomes -dbtype nucl -input_type blastdb
```

or

```
wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/
```

followed by 1 of

```
makeblastdb -in index.html -out genomes -dbtype nucl

makeblastdb -in ./index.html -out genomes -dbtype nucl -input_type blastdb
```

Please explain your commands and options, I don't even really know what ftp is or why this is necessary, I don't really know how to use the ftp once I download it, I just know that it seems like the only way to do it.

Comment: You need to input a fasta file of the genome(s) sequence, not an `index.html` file. You can't build a database without the sequences!

Comment: Well I actually just want to do the original query where I blast a sequence against a genome, I don't think I can have a fasta file for all the genomes, because I'm doing this on a lot of organisms. Basically if I can complete the original query I will be good.

Comment: @Chris_Rands The genomes I'm looking at are mammals and reptiles, so I can't just have the genome sequence locally. I don't know how to set up this database, and I don't know how to perform this query without the database

Comment: I don't have time to explain everything now, but of course you could download the genome sequences via an ftp, then build a database (or find a pre-built database), then query the database. If you have a small number of small sequences to query then just use a web interface like https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi

Comment: @Chris_Rands Downloading via ftp is probably the main problem I need to bypass. When I click the ftp links on websites, the database downloads and I've tried to drag the location of the ftp folder('/Volumes/genomes/') and type the command and I get this `makeblastdb -in /Volumes/genomes -out genomes -dbtype nucl -input_type blastdb
BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [/Volumes/genomes] in search path [/Users/sjg970/Desktop/BlastFolder::]` So my main problem is using the ftp which I have downloaded. I don't know how to do that

Comment: As you can read [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279675/), Blast offers a `-remote` flag that lets you execute the search on the NCBI servers (I assume without having to download anything or set up your own database). If you go this route, just do some research on how fast you can make calls (so that you don't overload them)

Comment: @nbryans I can use remote, but I want to specify one specific organism to blast against, from what I've seen everywhere else, it sounds like the only way to do this is by downloading the genome sequences by ftp.

Comment: Why not blast against all organisms, and they filter the results AFTER for the organisms you want?

Comment: @nbryans Its about 50 genes for 20 or 30 organisms, all vertebrates

Comment: @nbryans I'm also now trying to execute script 'update_blastdb.pl' which came with the blast+ package but instead of executing when I run it, it looks like a manual page opens

Comment: @Chris_Rands The reason I use index.html is because that is the file I obtain when I do `wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/`

Comment: Bob, we've deviated too far for SO and you obviously need a lot of help, find a colleague or teacher who can talk to you and explain

Comment: @Chris_Rands I only need one question answered. How can I blast one gene against a genome on the command line. If exact instructions can be posted I'll be good.

or alternatively

How can I download a database via ftp so that I can use this database in blast. This will also solve my problem

Comment: As user chris.mit7 points out [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/46279/), it should be possible to combine the `-remote` flag with the `-entrez_query` flag to get results for a single species at a time. For query a particular species, say Homo Sapiens, you could modify your command to the following:

    blastn -query $Gene -db nr -out Acan_blast.txt -evalue 0.00001 -outfmt 6 -entrez_query "Homo Sapiens[Organism]"

Comment: @nbryans I think that did it, thanks! Can you explain nr though, I never specified this as a database so I don't understand how it worked. Also, can I narrow it to just refseq?

Comment: I don't really know how it works, I was just going on the research of chris.mit7. You'll have to do some digging yourself into what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user chris.mit7 points out [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/46279/), it should be possible to combine the `-remote` flag with the `-entrez_query` flag to get results for a single species at a time. For query a particular species, say Homo Sapiens, you could modify your command to the following:

```
blastn -query $Gene -db nr -out Acan_blast.txt -evalue 0.00001 -outfmt 6
```